# Get the pagination parameter conditional

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I used the below in .htaccess file. From the url I have to get the results 1) **city** based 2) **city** based with pagination 3) **City and Category** based 4) **city and category** based with pagination.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+filter\.php?cityselect=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %9? [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ store.php?city=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ store.php?city=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ store.php?city=$1&category=$2&page=$3 [QSA,L]
```

I need to refine the results for these type of conditions
1. www.domain.com/cityname
2. www.domain.com/cityname/1
3. www.domain.com/cityname/category
4. www.domain.com/cityname/category/2

print_r($_GET) : If I use 3rd link then $_GET['page'] parameter is calling, here I need $_GET['category'] and everywhere last parameter is the page number. How to do this conditional format of getting the parameter values.

Comment: Question isn't very clear. Can you clarify which URL is giving problem to you.

Comment: I modified the question and I think it may understand now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+filter\.php?cityselect=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ store.php?city=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ store.php?city=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ store.php?city=$1&category=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ store.php?city=$1&category=$2&page=$3 [QSA,L]
```